# Flex4, AS3 app that makes/exports SWFs

Tags: apache-flex, flash, export, save

I want to make an app that allows the user to add their own content (pics, movie clips, songs) and then the app saves/exports the content as a SWF so that the users can use the exported swf wherever they like. Can this be done? What do I need to look into?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. You should look into the Flex framework command line compiler.